# Azure VM, unable to connect from internet on ports configured (9089-9095)

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, nic, telnet, network-security-group

I have created a VM on Azure with below steps:-

- Created VM
- Assigned a public static IP
- Created a new Virtual Network (Subnet default - (10.0.0.0/24)
- Did not create a NSG initially (NIC NSG was NONE - Not BASIC OR ADVANCE)
- No firewall or loadbalancer
- At this point my team could access port 22 and asked me to enable ports 9089-9095 for testing APIs
- Created a NSG and associated with both Network interface (Basic) and Virtual network
- Inbound rules I opened up all ports with maximum priority
- I also enabled IP forwarding for NIC
- No Route tables configured. No NAT configured
- Right now as well I am able to access port 22 only

Telnet to any other port responds with:

> Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond :9091

Comment: A service must be running on the port before you can connect to it. But it sounds like your other team members will take care of this.

Comment: The other team wants to access my VM using a public IP. They have asked for access to the VM using ports 9089- 9095. As per them they need this to test APIs

Comment: Yes, but is anything running on ports 9089-9095? What protocol is the process expected to respond to on those ports?

Comment: So based on above and google, do i need a application gateway?

Comment: No, the other team needs to start a service.

Comment: Should it not be that the VM has to have a listener on that port?

Comment: I get your point now

Comment: Now port 9090 is working but 9091-9095 are not responding. Netstat shows all are listening. Any reason one port is responding, others are not?

Comment: There are really only 3 reasons why something would not respond. 1. Nothing is listening on the port, 2. the local firewall on the VM is blocking access, 3. An NSG is blocking access, that's pretty much it